# Show if page URL matches string in classic ASP?

Tags: asp-classic

I'm trying to create an if statement which shows a line of JavaScript only if the current page URL matches a given string.  Here's some pseudo code:

```
if URL matches ("example.com/sitename/") then
response.Write("<script='file.js'></script>")
end if
```

The problem is how do I check whether the URL of the current page matches the string?

Many thanks!

---

Thanks for your responses.  I'm trying to make it a little more complicated with an array of possible URL matches.  I've created the following asp, but it doesn't work properly.  The script is being written on a page where the URL doesn't match.  Is there anything that looks wrong?  I can't figure it out!

```
<%
    Dim pageURL 

    pageURL = Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & Request.ServerVariables("URL")
    URLArray = Array("example.net/folder1/","example.net/folder2/")
    For Each URLsnippet In URLArray
        if instr(pageURL, URLsnippet) then
            response.Write("<!--BEGIN EXCLUDE--><script type='text/javascript' src='script.js'></script><!--END EXCLUDE-->")
        else
        end if
    Next
%>
```

It should match URLs matching example.net/folder1 and example.net/folder2, but it's also matching example.net folder3!

Answer (score 1):

try

```
if Request.ServerVariables("URL") = "/myurl.com/script.asp" then
 ' do stuff
end if
```

Comment: to get site.com (hostname environment variable value) use Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST")

Answer (score 1):

If you just want the url try this

```
var url = "<%=Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & Request.ServerVariables("URL")";
if(url == "site.com/script.asp")
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

If you also need the querystring try

```
var url = "<%=Request.ServerVariables("SERVER_NAME") & Request.ServerVariables("URL") & "?" & Request.Querystring%>";
if(url == "site.com/script.asp?var=123")
{
    //Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses.  I'm trying to make it a little more complicated with an array of possible URL matches.  I've created the following asp, but it doesn't work properly.  It's writing on a page where the URL doesn't match.  Is there anything that looks wrong?  I can't figure it out!

Comment: @Katie7 I've just created a testpage and it seems to work fine. Did you by any chance use = instead of == to compare the url in javascript?